# C++ List with string as key

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm new to C++ and trying to store and read integers from a map using strings as key. This question is probably duplicate but I tried many ways and none of them worked :/

Thank you for helping out :)

Specific question: How do you store and get objects from a map while using string as key and avoiding duplicate entries?

```
#include <map>
std::map<std::string, int> relation_map;
void setRelationState(std::string guid, int rel){
    if (relation_map.find(guid) != relation_map.end()){
        std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = relation_map.find(guid);
        it->second = rel;
        return;
    }
    relation_map.insert(pair<std::string, int>(guid, rel));
}
int getRelationState(std::string guid){
    if (relation_map.find(guid) != relation_map.end())return relation_map[guid];
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Read about `map::operator[]`.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There is no error. It simply wont work as intended.

Comment: Your `setRelationState` is equivalent to `relation_map[guid] = rel;`, but less efficient. What do you mean by "avoiding duplicate entries"? A map has exactly one entry per key.

Comment: Yeah, but the map only compares the pointers of the strings as far as i know. So "hello" and "hello" might not be the same key for the map and thus be duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to c++ , Please use the below code as a refernce to doing the things u want.. 
   //Declare Map

```
std::map <int, std::string> stdBindList;
std::map <int, std::string>::iterator pos;

//Add Elements

stdBindList.insert (std::pair<int,std::string>(15,”a”)); // 1
stdBindList.insert (std::pair<int,std::string>(22,”b”)); // 2

stdBindList.insert (std::pair<int,std::string>(12,”c”)); // 3
stdBindList.insert (std::pair<int,std::string>(15,”d”)); // 4
stdBindList.insert (std::pair<int,std::string>(5,”e”)); // 5
stdBindList.insert (std::pair<int,std::string>(5,”f”)); // 6
stdBindList.insert (std::pair<int,std::string>(2,”g”)); // 7

stdBindList.insert (std::pair<int,std::string>(5,”h”)); // 8
stdBindList.insert (std::pair<int,std::string>(5,”i”)); // 9

//iterate and print

for (pos = stdBindList.begin();pos!=stdBindList.end();pos++)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reference. I tried to use it, but i guess I did something wrong: http://pastebin.com/AQTKfKgp